# Reactive Forms : array property being transformed to object

Tags: angular, angular-forms

The issue can be seen in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hsfxf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) :

I have a payload :

```js
payload = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'This is the payload',
  children: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Child 1' }
  ],
};
```

I create a form group out of that :

```js
this.form = this.fb.group(this.payload);
```

I then display the value of the form :

```js
{{ form?.value | json }}
```

And the result is :

```json
{ "id": 1, "name": "This is the payload", "children": { "id": 1, "name": "Child 1" } }
```

As you can see, the `children` property went from an array, to an object.

1. How did that happen ?
2. Is it possible to stop Angular from doing that ?
3. If I need to use a formArray, is there a way to make it automatic ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare an array of array, as group takes array as argument [value, ...validators] :

```
payload = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'This is the payload',
    children: [[
      { id: 1, name: 'Child 1' },
    ]],
  };
```

To declare an array value according to [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) :

```
this.fb.group({
   anArray: [[]]
});

// OR
this.fb.group({
   anArray: this.fb.array([])
});

// OR
this.fb.group({
   anArray: new FormControl([])
});
```

If you want to make dynamic forms, have a look at [this angular.io page](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form).

Comment: Thank you, so this brings the question, is there a way to automatically create a double array (or `fb.array`) from a simple array ? Or do I have to iterate over every property and test if it's an array, then change it to double array ?

Comment: The angular.io link I've shared in the post, explains that for dynamic forms, you could create a `YourModelControlService` that will transform an object to form group. In your case, you will need to identify if it's an array and use `fb.array` in the `toFormGroup` function.

Comment: Didn't see the link, thank you ! I'm going home now, but I will definitely look at it when I come back on Monday.